# My professor says this is NOT a typo, but this does not appear to be logically valid.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> $$\begin{array}{rlll}
>  1. & \sim H \lor \sim G & \text{Premise} & \\
>  2. & H\land (G\lor H)     & \text{Premise} & \text{DEDUCE $F\& H$}
>  \end{array}$$

Using the rules of inference from standard propositional logic, we have to deduce $F \land H$.

Well, if we can deduce $F \land H$, we can also deduce $F$ through simplification. That means that these two premises can imply any statement, $F$, ever.

It does not appear possible to deduce the conclusion.

I feel like the only thing we can deduce is $H \land \sim G$. I even thought of what appears to be a counterexample. Let

- $H$: I live at home.
- $G$: I own a piece of gold.
- $F$: I own a Ferrari.

Premise 1 translates to "It is not the case that I live at home or it is not the case that I own a piece of gold." which is true. Premise 2 translates to "I live at home and either I own a piece of gold or I live at home." which is also true.

However, the conclusion $F \land H$ translates to "I own a Ferrari and I live at home", which is false.

(original scan of problem [here](http://i3.photobucket.com/albums/y89/jdinatale/typo_zps48d4d2d5.png))

Comment: Your analysis seems correct to me.

Comment: You're right, assuming that the problem is stated correctly.

Comment: You are right, but are these the only two assumptions given? There is nothing about $F$?

Comment: You are right that the conjunction of the premises is equivalent to H&~G. Since (H&~G)$\rightarrow$(F&H) is not a tautology, F&H cannot be deduced.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan The idea was probably to deduce a contradiction ($\sim G$ and $G$, probably), from which everything, including $F$, can be deduced.

Comment: Perhaps the instructor made this mistake: if he wasn't thinking carefully he might have taken premise 2 to imply G&H, and premise 1 is of course equivalent to ~(G&H), so by the explosion principle, you can deduce anything from them. In that case he would have expected many students to think there must be a typo at first.

Comment: Perhaps you should be discussing this with your professor, not with us...

Comment: what do you mean by "the rules of inference from standard propositional logic" each book has its own "the rules of inference from standard propositional logic"

Comment: None of them qualify as wffs, so you can "deduce" whatever you want.  If intended as wffs, though, you do seem to speak correctly, but I'd talk to your professor as GEdgar recommends.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that Premise 1 is meant to be:
$  \lnot ( H \lor \lnot G ) $
which simplifies to:
$ \lnot H \land G $
and from which it follows, by and-ing to the simplification of Premise 2 as simply H:
$ H \land \lnot H  \land G $
and then simply:
$ False $

From a falsehood, one can of course imply everything.

Answer (score 2):

We do an abbreviated truth-table analysis.

The sentence $H\land (G\lor H)$ is true precisely if $H$ is true.

To make $\lnot H \lor \lnot G$ true it is enough to make $G$ false.

Thus (1) and (2) are simultaneously satisfiable by making $G$ false and $H$ true.  They cannot therefore lead to a contradiction.

**Remark:** But the instructor could be right: it may be a mistake, not a typo.

Comment: If $H$ is false, then (2) is false..

Comment: Thanks! Had $G$ and $H$ transposed, $G$ comes before $H$.

Comment: Hey guys, it was a mistake. The professor found the mistake after I emailed a second time. This thread is no longer necessary.

Comment: @user2521987: Good work!${}{}{}{}{}$